# Как запустить код через Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет! Недавно начал учить js и скачал VS Code( до того работал только в Visual Studio). Потом установил все необходимое, по гайдам, и написал простенький код для начала

```
console.log(“Hello World”);
```

Когда запускаю код, через ctrl + alt + N мне вьіводится ошибка: Node.js не является используемой командой, что то вроде того, видел похожий вопрос, у меня потому что нет руського язіка просто вьіводится Node и куча символов (сели что у меня нет папки Node.js и я не знаю как не создать)Как запустить код? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Кавычки неправильные. Это книжные кавычки.

Comment: js можно и в Visual Studio пилить, там все необходимое есть из коробки

Comment: _И мне вьіводится ошибка_ - что ты делаешь, чтобы начала показываться ошибка? Какая ошибка показывается, полный текст?

Comment: попробуйте установить node js и перезапустить vs code

Comment: @Grundy запускаю код через ctrl + alt + N и мне вьіводится ошибка: Node.js не является используемой командой, что то вроде того, видел похожий вопрос, у меня потому что нет руського якзьіка просто вьіводится Node и куча символов

Comment: @eternal пробувал уже много раз, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Скачать Node JS с официального ресурса - [ссылка](https://nodejs.org/en/)

**2.** Установить его **"глобально"** к себе на компьютер (как обычную программу).

**Использование:**

**3.** Открыть VSCode и нажать **Ctrl + ~** (~ - где буква ё). Внизу редактора кода, откроется терминал. (Скорее всего "powershell" или "bush", в крайнем случае "cmd".

**4.** В поле терминала ввести команду **"node -v"** и нажать **enter**. Если терминал вернул версию Node JS (например **v16.18.0**) значит установлено все верно.

**5.** Теперь можно либо выполнять .js файлы либо писать код самому.

***5.1*** Писать код самому (Вводим в терминал **node** и **enter**) дальше как в обычном JavaScript, все написанное будет храниться в пределах сессии. Выйти из Node  - **Ctrl + C** или **.exit**.

***5.2*** Выполнять .js файлы  - в терминале пишем **node и путь к файлу** (относительно корня папки) например: **node index.js**

Comment: А что долать если я написал и запустил код, но в терминале ничего не вьіводится? Просто пустая строчка. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вариаций может быть куча. Как запустил? Какой код запустил? Интерпретатор Javascript читает (выполняет) документ сверху вниз. Если ничего не выводится в консоль, в терминале ничего и не покажет.

Comment: Запустил через ваш пункт 5.2, код самьій простой: console.log(“Hello World”)

Comment: А, все кажется заработало) у меня бьіло в терминале бьіло написано node, сейчас включил компьютер изменилось на powershell) Спасибо большое за помощь!